# Basis for subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ spanned by five vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find a basis for the subspace $W$ of $\Bbb R^4$ spanned by the set of vectors
>   $$\{[1,1,0,-1],[0,1,2,1],[1,0,1,-1],[1,1,-6,-3],[-1,-5,1,0]\}.$$
>   What is $\dim W$?

This is my working. Is it correct?
[image: Working]

Comment: In what you wrote, notice that in $2a_2+a_3-6a_4-a_5$ before $a_5$ should be plus sign

Comment: Thank you, but what should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: make a matrix with rows as the given vectors. Row reduce it. The number of pivots will give you the dimension.

Comment: So, what I did is not on the right track?

Comment: @ikd29123 Actually, it depends on what you were taught. You can look at your problem from both ways: What you did amounts to writing a matrix with vectors as its columns. What I suggest is to write them as rows of a matrix. If you know how to finish what you started, you can do this. If not, try the method I suggested and think why it works.

Comment: Oh, both of them works, and your way is easier. Thank you! Can you tell me why your method can work?

Comment: Again, the answer depends on what you are aware of. If I say that "multiplication from the left by an invertible matrix does not change the row space" will I answer your question?